# Set a custom format for a number field in a SharePoint content type

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

When I create a content type for SharePoint in XML in Visual Studio. Is it possible to create a field with the Type "Number" and give it a custom format? I don't want the thousands separator, but for some reasons I can't use the type "Integer" ...

EDIT: I tried this without success ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Element (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0xMyId"
               Name="MyType"
               Group="MyGroup"
               Description="..."
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{5231bb5f-37c8-4ca8-b256-58337cfe82d3}" Name="Right_ID" DisplayName="Right ID" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Required="TRUE" />
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>

  <Field ID="{5231bb5f-37c8-4ca8-b256-58337cfe82d3}"
         Type="Number"
         Commas="FALSE"
         Decimals="0"
         Name="Right_ID"
         Group="My Group"
         DisplayName="Right ID"
         StaticName="Right_ID"
         Hidden="FALSE"
         Required="TRUE"
         Sealed="FALSE" />
</Elements>
```

Maybe I should add, that the target system has german culture, so the thousands separator is . (dot) not , (comma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating a custom field, you should be able to set Commas to FALSE in the [Field Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979575.aspx). But that attribute is not listed as supported in the [FieldRef Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225.aspx) of a Content Type.

EDIT:

I'm beginning to wonder if Commas does not work on Number regardless of locale.

From MSDN (emphasis mine):

> Integer   Allows for positive or
>   negative integer values. **The Commas
>   and NegativeFormat attributes are used
>   to specify integer formatting.**
>   Corresponds to the int SQL data type.

and

> Number   Allows for a floating point
>   number to be entered. This field is
>   sortable and groupable. Numbers
>   entered are parsed according to the
>   current locale settings for decimal
>   points and thousand separators.
>   Negative numbers can be indicated by
>   wrapping them in parentheses or by
>   using a negative symbol. **The following attributes can be used in conjunction with the Number attribute to specify number formatting: Decimals, Div, Max, Min, Mult, and Percentage.**

With this, to remove the thousands separator I would either:

1. Try Integer again
2. Create a Calculated field based on the Number field that removes the comma by [converting to text](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/3f92f065-3c7c-4217-a335-e7093e475718).

Comment: I've set  <Field ID="<guid>" Type="Number" Commas="FALSE" Decimals="0" ... /> but it still displays a thousands separator (".", for target system is german) ...

Comment: Noooooooooo ... again my hopes scatter on the SharePoint horizon ... thanks anyway Rich.